# EBPF: pointer arithmetic on PTR_TO_PACKET_END prohibited

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ebpf

I am trying to write a kernel module for filtering using the following [example](https://github.com/badboy/ebpf-icmp-ping/blob/master/bpf.c). On Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 5.3.0 it's compiled and works perfectly fine.

However, when the same example is compiled on Debian 10 with kernel 4.19.0 compilation emits another byte-code, which is rejected when trying to load it to kernel by the kernel's verifier with error:

```
Prog section 'action' rejected: Permission denied (13)!
 - Type:         4
 - Instructions: 108 (0 over limit)
 - License:      GPL

Verifier analysis:

0: (bf) r6 = r1
1: (61) r2 = *(u32 *)(r6 +84)
2: (67) r2 <<= 32
3: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r6 +80)
4: (4f) r2 |= r1
R2 pointer arithmetic on PTR_TO_PACKET_END prohibited

Error fetching program/map!
bad action parsing
parse_action: bad value (6:bpf)!
Illegal "action"
```

What can be the issue? Is there a bug somewhere in kernel, compiler, verifier or the example? Versions of clang and llc match on both systems: 6.0.0 for both.

Update 1:
Versions of OSes:

- Ubuntu: Linux 5.3.0-40-generic #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Debian: Linux 4.19.0-6-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) i686 GNU/Linux

Versions of compilers:

- Ubuntu: clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final); Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
- Debian: clang version 6.0.1-10 (tags/RELEASE_601/final); Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: This is not a kernel module, this is a BPF program. The verifier is evolving and has changed between kernels 4.19 and 5.3, so it could be that. But you also mentioned that the bytecode produced by clang/llc was different on your two systems, so that's another possibility. What differences do you get exactly? Also, what does your BPF code look like? These `r2 <<= 32`,  `r2 |= r1` seem strange to me, not sure what you're trying to do with `skb->data_end`.

Comment: Sorry for messing up with the terminology, corrected that. By BPF code do you mean the C EBPF code? If yes, it is the one from example from the question, just a copy-paste of it for the experiments

Comment: Does the beginning (first 5-10 instructions) of the BPF program from the 4.19 system match the beginning of the BPF program from the 5.3 system? You can check that with `llvm-objdump -D bpf.o`.

Comment: @pchaigno no, they are not. I have created a Gist with assembly output from both systems, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/Akvinikym/9b8c2bad9a98206ea839ac9fbeb2ec5c)

Comment: Not sure what happened on the version on Debian. I don't understand how you obtain different bytecodes if using the same clang/LLVM version for both, though :/. Did you try to load on Debian the object file that you compiled on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, loading Ubuntu obj to Debian works perfectly :) My suggestion is that as kernels are different, compiler thus uses different implementations of kernal utilities, and this leads us to different bytecode. But, the EBPF code seems perfectly legal, so probably it should not lead to any errors.

Comment: Yeah it's possible that kernel headers are different... But the BPF bytecode you got on Debian clearly looks wrong, and I wouldn't expect that to happen in such a way. Could you compile it with the `-g` flag and dump with `llvm-objdump -S bpf.o` (instead of `-d`)? I'd be curious to see what instructions it tried to translate this way.

Comment: @Qeole I have updated the Gist: [link](https://gist.github.com/Akvinikym/9b8c2bad9a98206ea839ac9fbeb2ec5c), it's now in the second file

Comment: Hmm that didn't work. I tried to reproduce on my side on Debian, kernel 4.19 and clang-6.0, but I get normal, working code :/. Sorry, not sure how I can help debug this one.

Comment: That's really strange. Could it also be somehow related to the fact that Debian is inside a virtual machine? I don't think so, but still

Comment: I don't think either

Comment: @KotovP Could you add the output of `uname -a` and `clang --version` to your original post for both systems? How did you install Clang on each system? Is the VM running in 32bit mode?

Comment: I have added the output. Looks like VM is in 32bit mode. Clang was installed via apt-get on both systems